# Initializing font takes a long time

Tags: python, pygame

Initializing font takes a long time. Here I am initializing the Arial font to be used later in the program:

```
pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 30)
```

However this takes about 30 seconds to execute every time I start up the program. Is this supposed to happen?

I'm testing it on macOS Sierra.

Comment: I assume you're timing that one line in isolation?

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Yes, just that line of code takes about half a minute to complete.

Comment: Have you tried other system fonts?

Comment: Yup, same result.

Comment: Still no luck? I'm not on OS X I'm afraid.

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: Alright, I can't handle the suspense any longer. I'll see if I can replicate the issue on Windows 10.

Comment: No answers yet, so I'll take a stab at it. Could you show us some of the context, ie. the code immediately around that line. Don't have much else to go on...

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake [Just that line.](http://imgur.com/1DeYpfL.png) I think this is a bug specific to OS X / macOS.

Comment: `pygame.font.init()`

Comment: I can tell you that `font.init()` wasn't the problem, as it finishes executing right away.

Comment: I think you're right that this bug is specific to macOS.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake If you were wondering what the answer is, XQuartz was the reason why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the issue was caused by `fc-cache` in XQuartz not able to cache fonts properly ([Bug 97546](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97546)). After updating XQuartz from 2.7.10 to 2.7.11 the speed is back to normal.

Comment: Oh the joys of accepting your own answer! Nice detective work, btw. :P

Answer (score 0):

I ran this:

```
import pygame
pygame.font.init()
pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 30)
```

and it executes in less than 0.2s on Linux. You should file a bug report for this.